# Which fragment library should I import?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am implementing fragments with a DrawerLayout. I have 2 options when I import Fragments

1. android.support.v4.app
2. android.app

Which one should I use ? I dont see any difference except it seems like the `android.support.v4.app` has no support for `objectAnimator`.

What do you suggest ?

Edit: I only plan on supporting API level  14 and higher...

Comment: Better to use `android.support.v4.app`, because here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/package-summary.html, docs say `Support android.app classes to assist with development of applications for android API level 4 or later. The main features here are backwards-compatible versions of FragmentManager and LoaderManager.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on whether you are using Support Library.

If you are using fragments below api level 11 then use `android.support.v4.app`. In this case you will extend `FragmentActivity` which is the base class of support based fragments.

If you are using fragments in api level 11 and above use `android.app`. In this case you will extend standard `Activity`.

Take a look at the below link and decide on what versions your app should run. Depending on that decide whether you need support library or not.

https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

> I only plan on supporting API level 14 and higher...

Then there is no need to use support library. Use

```
import android.app.Fragment
```

and extend standard `Activity`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using support libary for drawerlayout then you should use android.support.v4.app for fragments.

Comment: What do you mean ? I only have the ability to add android.support.v4.app for DrawerLayout. Should I use something different?

Comment: edited my answer. You should use v4 libary for drawer layout. if you intend to use action bar with support library, then you should use appcompat v7 library.

Comment: Is there an example using appcompat v7 library with action bar and DrawerLayout?

Comment: Here is the link for http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: This is what I implemented with "android.app" not "android.support.v4.app." In this link I didn't see any mention of "appcompat v7 library"....Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use open-source "AndroidX" Support Library nowadays.

You can start from here [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx)